# Angular 2 : access to a route from another module

Tags: angular

Here I have my own module and I want to access to my route foo-detail from outside of my foo module's scope.

```
//app/bar/foo/foo.module.ts
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }  from '@angular/common';
import { FooComponent } from './foo.component';
import { FooRoutingModule } from './foo.routing';
import { DetailFoo } from './detailFoo/detailFoo.component';
import { ListFooComponent } from './listFoo/listFoo.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FooRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    FooComponent,
    DetailFoo,
    ListFooComponent
  ]
})
export declare class FooModule {}
```

And its own routing file

```
//app/bar/foo/foo.routing.ts

import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule }  from '@angular/router';

import { FooComponent } from './foo.component';
import { ListFooComponent } from './listFoo/listFoo.component';
import { DetailFoo } from './detailFoo/detailFoo.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'foo', component: FooComponent },
  { path: 'foo-list', component: ListFooComponent },
  { path: 'foo-detail', component: DetailFoo }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class FooRoutingModule {}
```

I try to include my module inside another module so we can reach routes of module foo inside module bar.

```
//app/bar/bar.module.ts

import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }  from '@angular/common';

import { routing }       from './bar.routing';

import { Bar } from './bar.component';
import { FooComponent } from '../bar/foo/foo.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, routing],
  declarations: [Bar,FooComponent]
})
export class BarModule {
}





//app/bar/bar.routing.ts

import { Routes, RouterModule }  from '@angular/router';
import { Bar } from './bar.component';
import { FooComponent } from '../bar/foo/foo.component';
// noinspection TypeScriptValidateTypes
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => System.import('./login/login.module')
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    loadChildren: () => System.import('./register/register.module')
  },
  {
    path: 'bar',
    component: Bar,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: () => System.import('./dashboard/dashboard.module') },
      { path: 'editors', loadChildren: () => System.import('./editors/editors.module') },
      { path: 'test',  loadChildren: () => System.import('./test/test.module') }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'foo-module',
    component: FooComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'foo', loadChildren: () => System.import('./foo/foo.module') }
    ]
  }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

And here is my issue, I tried here to do every kind of things, but I can't access to my routes of Foo from Bar. 
I tried here in bar.routing.ts

```
import { DetailFoo } from '../bar/foo/detailFoo/detailFoo.component';
```

and route

```
path: 'foo-detail',component: detailFoo
```

I did many tests, with directly the component, or the module, or the routing. Nothing make me access to some routes of Foo from Bar module.

What did I missed. Do I have to provide a dependency injection in some way that i forgot?

EDIT
I use ng2-admin module, and my routes ar all gathered in a const PAGES_MENU
which contains this :

```
        {
            path: 'arrival-list',
            data: {
              menu: {
                title: 'Liste',
              }
            }
          },
```

here we fill it into MENU

```
import { PAGES_MENU } from './pages/pages.menu';

export const MENU = [
  ...PAGES_MENU
];
```

And finally ng2-admin makes a cloneDeep. It might be our problem!

```
  public routes = _.cloneDeep(MENU); // we're creating a deep copy since we are going to change that object
```

TLDR;
How can i access to a route of a module inside of another module?

Comment: What does " want to access to my route" mean? You want navigate to that route? What is the problem? What are you trying to do and what is the  current behavior and the expected behavior?

Comment: my app redirects me all the time to dashboard, which is the polite way yo tell me page not found. I want to access to my route foo-detail from module bar. when i call this route with a route link in a template of module foo it works, but when I do it from module bar, it redirects me to dashboard

Comment: How do you navigate? `routerLink`, `router.navigate(...)`, ...?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I just edited my questions with more precision. Please note that I use ng2-admin which manages this part on its side. So to answer to your question, ng2-admin use cloneDeep for those routes